# Get a value associated with a key in an array of JSON objects in a Logic App expression

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Given this JSON hash:

```
{
    "id": 55555,
    "name": "111111",
    "custom_data_field": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Vehicle Type",
            "value": "Coach"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Vendor",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the `value` associated with each `label`.

I'm able to get the `value` using the array's index:

```
@item()?['custom_data_field'][0]['value'] # Coach
@item()?['custom_data_field'][1]['value'] # 1
```

But this is a bit fragile.

This syntax doesn't work:

```
@item()?['custom_data_field'][@label=='Vehicle Type']['value'] # Coach
@item()?['custom_data_field'][@label=='Vendor']['value'] # 1
```

Is there a way to do this reliably?

Comment: One way might be with FilterArray action to get just that array element but I can't remember trying this.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action

Comment: Hi craig, may I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Answer (score 5):

According to the description of your question, it seems the data `{"id": 55555, "name": "111111"....}` you provided is an item of a array list because your expression begins with `item()` (I guess you use this expression in a "For each" or something else loop action). And `custom_data_field` is array under the item, you want to do filter/select operation to get the `value` which its `label` equals `Vehicle Type` just by the expression. I don't think we can do it just in one expression (because the `label` and `value` are not key-value map, we can not do the filter/select in expression easily).

To meet the requirement, we need to use a more sophisticated approach such as "Filter array" action mentioned by Scott in comments. We need to set the array `custom_data_field` to the input box("From" box) of the "Filter array" action.
[image]

And then add the filter condition.
[image]

After running the logic app, it will filter the items by the filter condition. 
[image]

**As the filter action don't know how many items match the condition, so the output will always be a array but not an item or a record even if there is only one item matches the condition(`label` equals "Vehicle Type") in your `custom_data_field` list.**

So if you want to get the `value`, you need to get it by writing an expression as below screenshot.
[image]

Hope it helps~